# Load PDF document with PDF-LIB on Node gives "No PDF header found"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im loading a PDF document I have to modify on the fly with PDF-lib.

```
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');
```

The PDF file is built with Acrobat and its called dental_insurance.pdf.

I tried to load the file the following ways:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load("/documents/cards/dental_insurance.pdf")

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load("C:/Website/test/desk_routes/documents/cards/dental_insurance.pdf")

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load("./documents/cards/dental_insurance.pdf")

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load("../documents/cards/dental_insurance.pdf")
```

But no matter how I set the route where the file is located, I get this error:

> (node:15196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to parse
> PDF document (line:4 col:2 offset=27): No PDF header found

I checked at PDF-lib documentation, they only state the following to load a file:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load("...")
```

I dont believe the problem is on the PDF file since I get the very same error even if I enter a file that doesn't exist:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load("blablabla.pdf")
```

Thanks.

Comment: PDFDocument is not a built-in command and there's no npm package with that name, so can you tell us where that package is from?

Comment: If there's a command to load data, you could try first opening the file and reading the contents, then running loading that data, that way you could verify that the file has been loaded

Comment: Yes, I modified the question. It is PDF-Lib
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfdocument#static-load), `PDFDocument.load()` accepts a string which is the *contents* of the pdf file, not the name.

```
const fs = require('fs/promises'); //note fs/promises, not fs here

const pdfData = await fs.readFile('./documents/cards/dental_insurance.pdf');

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);
```

Comment: That worked perfect. Thanks Codebling.

Comment: Im wondering how to download in Angular

Comment: @pvg1975 why not ask a new question. Usually people use `axios` but depends what you mean by download.

Comment: @pvg1975 When I use Angular, I download files using file-saver: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: what if it's s3 url ?

Comment: @Ujjual you need to supply the contents of the document, regardless of where the file is hosted. Download/load the file into a variable, convert to base64, pass to function.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED - you need *readFileSync* in node version >= 18

```
import fs from "fs";
    

const buffer = await fs.readFileSync("./documents/cards/dental_insurance.pdf");
const document = await PDFDocument.load(buffer);
```

Comment: I suspect you are saying this because you tried to `await` `fs.readFile()` and it didn't work. `readFile()` in `fs` expects a callback, you need to use the Promises API to get the `await`able version of `readFile()`. This is `fs/promises` in Node 14+ and `fs.promises` in Node 10-13. Nothing has changed in Node 18+ in this respect. I am also wondering why you are using `await` with a sync call in your example.